# Read Text Line by Line in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, filereader, file-handling, readfile

I'm trying to read a text file using Scanner and split the text at Space and store it in the array but it does not read the whole text but it actually reading the last two lines.
I'm trying to read these lines:

Student [name= Uzair Siddiqui , Roll Number = 1234 address= karachi , phoneNumber= 03312345 , major= cs Courses= [DM, OOP] , GPA= 3.8 ]
Student [name= Zaid Haris , Roll Number = 2323 address= kaaaa , phoneNumber= 01315121 , major= dm Courses= [JAVA, CAL] , GPA= 3.8 ]

And I split the data at " " and storing it in a String array but it only stores the last lines i.e

Student [name= Zaid Haris , Roll Number = 2323 address= kaaaa , phoneNumber= 01315121 , major= dm Courses= [JAVA, CAL] , GPA= 3.8 ]

My Code is

```
        String [] strArr=new String[500];
        try {
            FileInputStream myObj = new FileInputStream("allStudents.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);


            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                strArr=data.split(" ");
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Looking for an answer asap. Thank you!

Comment: What format does the input come in as? is each student on a new line? Give an example of what your ideal outcome would be

Comment: `strArr = ` obviously does not mean 'append', that's a rather bizarre interpretation of what `=` might do. Don't use an array, that's not what they are for. Use a `List<String>`. `list.addAll(data.split(" "));` would be a decent start. You also need to apply try-with-resources here, and this is a very outdated way to read files in java. It also fails if the file is not in the right encoding, as you haven't specified it.

Comment: @StarshipladDev I wanted to store all the file text in an array by splitting it at space, but it only stores the last lines.

Comment: @rzwitserloot thanks for the help. I will try it.

Comment: Hi Uzair, consider this: you are initializing the strArr variable as a list of fixed length. But then, you are not using that space you just allocated: strArr is set equal to data.split, which is the last line you read. At each iteration, you just store the last line you read into the strArr variable.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is is that you are replacing 'StrArr' with the latest line read each time.

Try doing it with a 2D Array , where the first index is for each line, and the second is for each words split up by `" "` in that line

**example**:

```
        String[][] strArr=new String[numberOfLines][];
        try {
            FileInputStream myObj = new FileInputStream("allStudents.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            int count=0;
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine(); //YOUR ISSUE WAS HERE AND LINE BELOW
                strArr[count]=data.split(" ");
                count++;
            }
            myReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: There is no need to initialize the second dimension to 500. Also, consider using try-with-resources.

Comment: -UzairSiddiqui can you upvote and mark as answered? I'm 10 rep off less ads <3 

Hey @GDC , I'm a bit rusty as I moved to C# sharp for a while. I knew String[size][size1] woudl work, but couldn't confirm String[size][] , with latter initialization to the second index, would.
Thanks for the feedback, I will edit it as such.